# Firestore statistics

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to implement `google firestore` in my app, to collect some basic data about what options of app users use the most and how. Since it is not a small task, before I do, I would like to know, is there a way to get some statistics from that database and filter categories (all categories will be provided by users) like country, type of OS, version of app, and search for specific user by his id/email?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Firestore will have the functionality of providing statistics about the app user. However, most of the details you mentioned can be tracked with [Google Analytics for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics).

Additionally, it is also possible to create other Custom Events and log these events from your application, as mentioned in the [Log events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events) section of the documentation.

If you want to know what events are automatically logged, refer to the [Automatically collected events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069) page of the GA4 documentation.